# Will MySQL reorder where condition based on multi columns index order?

Tags: mysql, database

e.g., an index is `(column1,column2)`. Supposing we run a query `select * from some_table where column2 > 3 and column1<2`, will MySQL be smart enough to reorder query to `select * from some_table where  column1<2 and column2 > 3` and then use index `(column1,column2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL's optimizer can tell that boolean `AND` is algebraically commutative, that is, `A AND B` is logically the same as `B AND A`.

It can reorder terms to match index order when it can do so while preserving logical equivalence.

However, in the case you show, the condition on `column1` is a range condition, so MySQL can't use the index to search in the second column. The values in `column2` are sorted per value of column1, so they're practically in no order. Searching for rows where `column2 > 3` would have to search every subset of rows that match the first term anyway, and by that time, the storage engine will have read those rows into memory, so there's little value in using the index.